Proving that min(1,$\bullet$) is concave
I need to prove that the function $\min\{1,\bullet\}$ is concave. I was provided the following hint:
A function $\psi$ can be shown to be concave if and only if it can be written as $\psi(x)=\inf_{y\in Y}(x−y+\lambda_y)$, where $Y\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\{\lambda_y\}_{y\in Y} \subset \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$.
I came up with the following idea:
$Y=\{-1, 1\}=:\{y_1,y_2\}, \lambda_{y_1}=-x$ and $\lambda_{y_2}=1$. Thus I have the wanted result because if $x$ is smaller than $1$, then $\psi(x)=x$ and if $x$ is greater than $1$, I have that $\psi(x)=1$.
However, putting $\lambda_{y_1}=-x$ seems a bit awkward to me since it shouldn't depend on x. Am I wrong somewhere or does it work?
Edit: As @geetha290krm pointed out, the hint I was provided contained a typo. A function is concave if and only if it can be written as the infimum  of (possibly uncontably many) affine functions. The the infimum I stated should be $\psi(x)=\inf_{y\in Y}(xy+\lambda_y)$.
Thus, following my original idea, we would have $Y=\{0, 1\}=:\{y_1,y_2\}, \lambda_{y_1}=1$ and $\lambda_{y_2}=0$ to obtain the affine functions $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_2(x)=x$.
Anyway, thanks @zwim for your answer.

Your criterion for concavity is false.

$\min(1,x)=\begin{cases} x&x\le 1\\1&x\ge 1\end{cases}$
The function trivially concave on each if the intervals $(-\infty,1]$ and $[1,+\infty)$, what is interesting us is showing the cord is below the curve when we take one point in each interval.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1tddp89b28
Point $A=(a,a)$ with $a\le 1$ and point $B=(b,1)$ with $b\ge 1$.
Let $C\in[A,B]$ be defined by $C=A+(B-A)t$ with $t\in[0,1]$
i.e. $\begin{cases}C_x=a+(b-a)t\\C_y=a+(1-a)t\end{cases}$
$C_x=1\iff t_1=\frac{1-a}{b-a}$

In the interval $t\in[t_1,1]$ then

$C_y-1=a+\overbrace{(1-a)}^{\ge 0}t-1\le a+(1-a)\times 1-1=0$
so $C_y\le 1$ and $C$ is below the curve $y=1$

In the interval $t\in[0,t_1]$ then

$C_y-C_x=\Big(a+(1-a)t)-(a+(b-a)t\Big)=-t\overbrace{(b-1)}^{\ge 0}\le 0$
so $C_y\le C_x$ and $C$ is below the curve $y=x$
Overall $C_y\le \min(1,C_x)$ on the whole interval $t\in[0,1]$ therefore your function is concave.
